# XFCE desktop and work-space settings suddenly revert

Tags: 16.04, xfce, desktop-environments

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04LTS and I use XFCE as my desktop environment. I had tweaked a few settings to suite my experience. I was working on a java project using intelliJ-Idea and I wanted to open a folder from the IDE.

Check this screenshot [Selecting Folder from with in **IntelliJ**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v63U.png). Immediately my desktop turned from 
[image: this]

to

[image: this] 
(notice that most of the items from the right click menu are missing).

I tried googling the problem and read on [ubuntuforums.org](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2074797) that the only possible problem is **xfdesktop** not running but it was running. Does anyone have a solution(s)?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @damadam. I wanted to do that but I do not have  enough reps. Thank's again.

Comment: You don't need to thanks me, someone else would have do it if i don't do it